# Advanced Filter for JTable

Tags: java, regex, swing, jtable, rowfilter

I have a JTable that am Filtering in relation to JTextField input. It is only Filtering Rows based on the first characters. For example if My Column 2 has Values:

```
VALUES PARAMETER
PARAMETER VALUES
.
.
```

When I type V into the JTextfield it will show the row with `VALUES PARAMETER` and leave the row with `PARAMETER VALUES` I need an advanced Filter such that when I type V it will be able to show me the Two rows or any other rows where there is a Name Starting with the Value typed in the JTextField: Here is My Filter....(Part)

```
 jtfSearch.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            newFilter();
        }

        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            newFilter();
        }

        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            newFilter();
        }
    });
```

My Filter Method:

```
 public void newFilter() {
    RowFilter< MyTableModel, Object> rf = null;
    try {
        rf = RowFilter.regexFilter("^" + jtfSearch.getText(), 1);
    } catch (Exception as) {
        System.err.println(as);
        return;
    }
    sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
}
```

Is it an Issue of the Regex filter or what Should I do?

Comment: Am Not sure I understood that!!!

Comment: `I need an advanced Filter such that when I type V it will be able to show me the Two rows or any other rows where there is a Name Starting with the Value typed in the JTextField` ---> did you mean autocomplete ???

Comment: Not Auto Complete..I think My Issues was the `^` at the regex.

Comment: I miss reason for that, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that `jtfSearch.getText()` returns the text from the entire row, is this correct? If so, then presumably the issue is just that you have `"^"` at the start of your regex, take this out and it should match anywhere in the full row content.